# jQuery 1.9 to 3.1 upgrade ajax .load response is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am upgrading jQuery from 1.9 to 3.1 (big jump, I know). All is going well except the ajax .load call is now returning a blank "response".

In 1.9 the $('#id').load() works fine and I can log the response text.
Same call now using 3.1 the response is undefined.

I read the the .load for events was removed but I have not found anything pertaining to the ajax .load

Am I just missing a small little something.

```
$('#config').load(url, function(response, status, xhr){
    console.log(response);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(xhr);
    $('#config').show();
    $('#id_name').focus();
    $('#del_div').show();
});
```

the html file it is trying to load looks like the following.

```
<div>...stuff in here...</div><script>... some more js ...</script>
```

***Update***
I just realized that this is going through dajaxice and I know that is very outdated.  I would not be surprised if that is causing the issue.

Comment: Is the HTML being loaded correctly into the `#config` DIV?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean?  The code I posted has not changed. Except I added the console.logs

Comment: I never said the code changed. `.load()` does two things: it puts the response into the HTML of the `#config` DIV, and it also calls your callback function. The question says that the `response` in the callback function is empty, I wanted to know if it's also not putting it into the DIV.

Comment: If you go into the Network tab of DevTools, do you see the response being returned?

Comment: No, it is not putting anything into the div. It appears to be completely unchanged.

Comment: Do you see the correct response coming back in the Network tab?

Comment: Yes, I cleared the network history, clicked the button that calls the .load() and the response in the Network tab looks correct.  But it is not loading on the page.

Comment: dajaxice is bad - its last commit was more than 2 years ago and nowdays even its maker advises users not to use it.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I didn't choose it and we haven't had the time to remove it.